# google maps doesn't show map and does not show markers

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, google-maps, razor, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to put markers base on latitude and longitude on google maps that are store in my Db.

But I'm not viewing a map on my page and no markers.

Can't figure out what is the problem here.

I have `console.log` the markers & the results is an object I'm not sure if it should be so.

```
@if (item.Longitude != null)
    {
        <span class="js-latmaps">   @item.Latitude</span>
        <span class="js-longmaps">   @item.Longitude</span>
    }
    <div id="dvMap" style="width: 500px; height: 500px">
</div>

@section scripts {
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=<"LONG_NUMBER">libraries = places"></script> 

<script type = "text/javascript">

        var markers = [
            {
                "lat": $('.js-latmaps'),
                "lng": $('.js-longmaps')
            }
        ];
        console.log(markers);
        window.onload = function() {
            var mapOptions = {
                center: new window.google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng),
                zoom: 8,
                mapTypeId: window.google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var infoWindow = new window.google.maps.InfoWindow();
            var map = new window.google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);
            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                var data = markers[i];
                var myLatlng = new window.google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
                var marker = new window.google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myLatlng,
                    map: map

                });
                (function(marker, data) {
                    window.google.maps.event.addListener(marker,
                        "click",
                        function(e) {
                            infoWindow.setContent(data.description);
                            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                        });
                })(marker, data);
            }
        };
    </script>}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9z6t2m3q/

Comment: What console error you get?

Comment: No error at all

Comment: Add js fiddle to the question.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9z6t2m3q/ I have Added JS Fiddler

Comment: It's give an error of `SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'`

Comment: @Div I didn't write the API Key , just put it in <> <APIKeyHere>

Answer (score 1):

Just replace

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=<"LONG_NUMBER">libraries = places"></script>
```

by

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOURKEY&libraries=places></script>
```

Please note :

- To remove the `<>` around your API_KEY
- To add an `&` between your API_KEY and `libraries=places`
- To replace `libraries = places` by `libraries=places` (no space)

Comment: the <> is just for the q my key look like you wrote

Comment: I'm also calling `maps.googleapis.com` and not `maps.google.com`. Did you try it ?

Comment: Yeh, that didn't help, if I put the Lat\Long data manually it's fine . but when I send it dynamically then  looking at console .Log I c this values at  innerHTML "   32.0609752"
innerText "32.0609752"  so the value is pas there